# Sort tree which divides list into k parts python

Tags: python, sorting, merge, binary-tree

I understand how to sort a list using a binary tree. Eg. sort [ 1,3,5,6,7,3,4,2] from smallest to largest.   I recursively split the data into 2 parts each time until it becomes n lists. I then compare 2 lists at a time and append the smaller value into a new list.  I do not understand how to do this when it requiress me to splits a list into k parts each time. Eg. k=3. [1,3,5] [6,7,3] [4,2] .I could only find a solution in Java so could someone explain this to me using python?

Comment: This is **not** sorting using a binary tree. This is **merge sort**. Don't confuse it with **binary search tree sort** or **heap sort** which actually use binary trees.

Comment: The merge algorithm you're looking for is called [k-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm#K-way_merging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have k sublists. At every iteration, find the sublist whose first element is the smallest; append that element to the result list; advance one in that sublist and don't advance in the other sublists.

This is easier if you have a function `arg_min` or `min_with_index` that gives you the smallest element as well as its index (so you know which sublist it comes from).

Here are two equivalent ways of writing function `min_with_index` using python's builtin `min` to get the min, and `enumerate` to get the index:

```py
def min_with_index(it):
  return min(enumerate(it), key=lambda p:p[1])

import operator
def min_with_index(it):
  return min(enumerate(it), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

# >>> min_with_index([14,16,13,15])
# (2, 13)
```

This was for merging. Here are two different ways of splitting, using list slices:

```py
def split_kway_1(l, k):
  return [l[i::k] for i in range(k)]

def split_kway_2(l, k):
  j = (len(l)-1) // k + 1
  return [l[i:i+j] for i in range(0,len(l),j)]

def split_kway_3(l, k):
  j = len(l) // k
  result = [l[i:i+j] for i in range(0, j*(k-1), j)]
  result.append(l[j*(k-1):])
  return result

# >>> split_kway_1(list(range(10)), 3)
# [[0, 3, 6, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]]
# >>> split_kway_2(list(range(10)), 3)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
# >>> split_kway_3(list(range(10)), 3)
# [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]

# versions 2 and 3 differ only when the length of the list is not a multiple of k
```

And now we can combine splitting and merging to write merge sort:

```py
import operator

def split_kway(l, k):
  return [l[i::k] for i in range(k)]

def min_with_index(it):
  return min(enumerate(it), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

def merge_kway(list_of_sublists):
  result = []
  list_of_sublists = [l for l in list_of_sublists if len(l) > 0]
  while list_of_sublists:
    i,v = min_with_index(l[0] for l in list_of_sublists)
    result.append(v)
    if len(list_of_sublists[i]) > 1:
      list_of_sublists[i].pop(0) # advance in sublist i
    else:
      list_of_sublists.pop(i)    # remove sublist i which is now empty
  return result

def merge_sort_kway(l, k):
  if len(l) > 1:
    list_of_sublists = split_kway(l, k)
    list_of_sublists = [merge_sort_kway(l, k) for l in list_of_sublists]
    return merge_kway(list_of_sublists)
  else:
    return list(l)
```

See also: [Wikipedia on k-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm#K-way_merging)